# bootstrap floating css/widget/parts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am searching for the boot strap floating css/widget/parts samples.

I am googling around with some keyword like 'floating / fixed'  but only found sticky footer and header or some simple panel samples.

What my 'floating' means , div stays on the same place of window regardress of scroll.

like airbnb cacher panel.

(sorry this screenshot is japanese)

[image]

Comment: `position: fixed` might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap provides some class utilities such as `navbar-fixed-top` or `navbar-fixed-bottom` for specific components (a navigation bar in this case) because the component might need more than one line of CSS to be actually fixed.

Otherwise, bootstrap is not magic, it is just CSS under the hood. So if you need something to be fixed, then just use `position: fixed`.

Comment: Thanks I use potion:fixed instead of some bootstrap method. Aparently as you said, bootstrap is not magic. but it was not so difficult.